# Git deleting files upon branch checkout

Tags: git, version-control

I have a directory containing some code spread across multiple files. The code is not version controlled. So, I created a git repo at the top level. But, since there are several files in the directory, I only wanted to add the files I intend to modify to my git repo. I `git ignore`d the rest of the files.

But, here is a problem I run into.. In the beginning, my repo has no files. Then, I check in `foo.cpp` and `foo.hpp` on `branch1`. Then, without moving `HEAD`, I create `branch2` and also check in `bar.cpp` and `bar.hpp`. Now, if I checkout `branch1`, git deletes file `foo.cpp` and `foo.hpp`.

I guess git cleans up the file since it was not supposed to be there in `branch1`. Could you please tell me how do I work around this?

Comment: Can you please elaborate on what you want to accomplish? What you're describing is exactly what should happen.

Comment: @PhazePhusion How do I re-structure my workflow to incrementally add files to fit repo as needed, and yet retain the ability to go back in time such that files not already under version control won't be deleted when I do go back. Thanks.

Comment: do you mean git deletes `bar.cpp` and `bar.hpp` in your question? I would think that as `foo` is checked into `branch1`, it should be there when you check it out

Comment: The files aren't deleted, `foo` still exists on the `branch2` branch. Each branch is a "snapshot" of a repository. Each time you checkout that branch Git restores that snapshot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add `bar.cpp` and `bar.hpp` in `branch2`, you need to switch to `branch2` firstly, that means the HEAD need point to branch2.  And when you add files to a branch, you should use `git add` and `git commit` to add the files to version control. Assume your git structure as below:

```
/top level directory
      |___ .git      
      |___ /subfolder
                     |___ foo.cpp
                     |___ foo.hpp
                     |___ bar.cpp
                     |___ bar.hpp
                     |___ …
```

The whole steps should like this:

```
git init
git checkout -b branch1
git add subfolder/foo.cpp subfolder/foo.hpp
git commit -m 'commit message'
git checkout -b branch2
git add subfolder/bar.cpp subfolder/bar.hpp
git commit -m 'commit message'
```

Now no matter which branch you checkout, files in the related branch will not be lost.